# Acer Aspire One Battery Won't Charge

Tags: battery, acer-aspire

My Acer Aspire One D255 battery won't charge.  I bought a new battery and that wasn't the problem.  The battery light on the conputer won't light up either.  Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Is it the same battery as you had one before? I mean it should be support to your model also doesn't battery icon show up anything in the taskbar? Also which version of Windows you are using?

Comment: Examine closely the battery contacts on the computer, and make sure they are not bent/misaligned and there's nothing (eg, a wayward piece of tape) covering them.

Comment: Does the laptop operate correctly with the mains power connected?

Comment: First make sure you have the right power adapter.  A unit will often run with lower voltage than needed to charge the battery.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to recalibrate the battery. 
[Battery calibration](http://acer--uk.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5941/kw/battery%20calibration)
 *Source - Acer Support*

Battery calibration means getting better precision of the detected level of charge. Recalibration requires a complete cycle of charge and a complete cycle of discharge of the battery. In this article you will find the instructions for a correct calibration.

SOLUTION

Use the following steps to to re-calibrate the battery:

1. Turn the notebook or netbook off. Plug in your AC adapter.
2. Let the unit fully charge, until the battery LED turns off.
3. Turn on the computer and press the F8 key repeatedly when the first
   logo screen appears.
4. In the Windows Advanced Startup menu, select Safe Mode and press the ENTER key.
5. Unplug the unit and let the computer run on battery until it shuts down.

NOTE

The process of recalibration can take several hours, depending on the battery lifetime and age, and the configuration of your system.

Comment: Would be great if you give the link of the Source :)

Comment: @avirk It was not a user friendly site to grab the link from. The entire site will not come up from the link, BUT, it is in there now.

Answer (score 0):

A part of the motherboard can be fried. I'm working right now on a laptop where power module is burnt and it won't work from the wall socket, but works with a battery. I'm sure an opposite scenario is possible. I've found that out after I have completely disassembled the laptop and found a burnt fragment near the power module on the motherboard.

You may find the [Acer Asoure Ibe D255 service manual](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/Manuals/acer/2010/ServiceGuides/SG_Aspire_One_D255_20100729_BOOK.pdf) helpful. Page 113 of the PDF (printed as 103) shows steps on how to remove the motherboard.

Try it only if other solutions fail as putting a laptop back together is pretty cumbersome.